# Unable to store image in JSON

Tags: php, json

Below is my PHP code for storing a table which contains image (BLOB) column in JSON:

```
$query_search1 = "SELECT * FROM rocket WHERE username='".$rocketName."'";
$query_exec1 = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$query_search1) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));
$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_exec1)){
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec1)){
        $json['rocket_profile'][] = $row1;
    }
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

When I run this file, it just shows a blank page and doesn't show any error.
How do I store an image from MySQL with data type BLOB in JSON ?

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your scripts.

Comment: I think is best to store the URL of the image as string and save that image in a particular place like /images/image-name.jpg and store `/images/image-name.jpg` in the DB so you can retrieved that data easily. And use that url in any image like: <img src="/images/image-name.jpg" />

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a particular reason for storing image data inside of your database, a wiser solution would be to save the images to the web server and store a path to the saved image. This allows images to be cacheable, reduces the overhead of the database, and the speed of using filesystem references is much better.

If you do have a particular reason, then you will need to encode the binary data and process it later.

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec1)){
    $row1['picture'] = base64_encode($row1['picture']);
    $json['rocket_profile'][] = $row1;
}
```

You could then use the encoded image in your code. Be wary, though, that this is likely to be slower than just storing reference paths and, even if you were storing the encoded data instead of storing a binary blob.